# Form in bootstrap won't work.. Why?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, when I try to use my form in a bootstrap modal, it doesn't work. I suspect is has something to do with the PHP but I am not entirely sure.

The problem occurs when I click the submit button on the form. The document doesn't activate the php which should update the mysql, and then redirect you to another page, instead it just refreshes the current page. Keep in mind this is in a modal.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
if(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "header.php"){
    die("403 - Access Forbidden");
}
    $cookie_name = 'showmodal';
    $cookie_value = 'AlreadySawModal';
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (43200), '/'); // 43200 = 12hr
 ?> 
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>assets/css/<?php echo $theme;?>.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?phpecho $siteurl; ?>assets/css/addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>assets/css/<?php echo $themetype; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle"> You haven't voted in the past 12 hours!? </h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="resize">
    <?php
    $earnedpoints  = false;
    $insertnew     = false;
    $time          = time();
    $redirect      = "";
    $account       = $mysqli->real_escape_string(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', @$_POST['name']));
    $siteid        = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_POST['votingsite']);
    $checkacc      = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '$account'");
    $countcheckacc = $checkacc->num_rows;
    if ($countcheckacc == 0 && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $funct_error = "This account doesn't exist!";
    } elseif ($account == '' && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $funct_error = 'You need to put in a username!';
    } elseif (empty($_POST['votingsite']) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $funct_error = "Please select a voting site";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, SUM(times) as amount FROM " . $prefix . "votingrecords WHERE NOT account='' AND NOT account='0' AND account='" . $account . "' AND siteid = '" . $siteid . "'") or die('Error - Could not look up vote record!');
        $row       = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $sitequery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM " . $prefix . "vote WHERE id = '" . $siteid . "'");
        $vsite     = $sitequery->fetch_assoc();
        $gvp       = $vsite['gvp'];
        $gnx       = $vsite['gnx'];
        $timecalc  = $time - $row['date'];
        if ($row['amount'] == '' || $timecalc > $vsite['waittime']) {
            if ($row['amount'] == '') {
                $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO " . $prefix . "votingrecords (siteid, ip, account, date, times) VALUES ('" . $siteid . "', '" . $ipaddress . "', '" . $account . "', '" . $time . "', '1')") or die('Error - Could not insert vote records!');
            } else {
                $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $prefix . "votingrecords SET siteid = '" . $siteid . "', ip='" . $ipaddress . "', account='" . $account . "', date='" . $time . "', times='1' WHERE account='" . $account . "' AND siteid = '" . $siteid . "'") or die('Error - Could not update vote records!');
            }
            $earnedpoints = true;
            if ($earnedpoints == true) {
                if ($account != '') {
                    $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE accounts SET $colvp = $colvp + $gvp, $colnx = $colnx + $gnx WHERE name='" . $account . "'") or die('Error - Could not update account!');
                }
                $funct_msg = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0"; url=' . $vsite['link'] . '">';
                $redirect  = true;
            }
        } elseif ($timecalc < $vsite['waittime'] && $row['amount'] != '') {
            $funct_msg = 'You\'ve already voted for ' . $vsite['name'] . ' within the last ' . round($vsite['waittime'] / 3600) . ' hours!';
            $funct_msg .= '<br />Vote time: ' . date('M d\, h:i A', $row['date']);
        } else {
            $funct_error = 'Unknown Error';
        }
    }
    if ($redirect == true) {
        echo $funct_msg;
    }

    else {
?> 
<form method="post">  
    <?php
        if (isset($funct_msg)) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $funct_msg . '</div>';
        }
        if (isset($funct_error)) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $funct_error . '</div>';
        }
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from " . $prefix . "vote");
        if ($query->num_rows == 0) {
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Your administrator has not added any voting sites yet!</div>";
        }
        echo "
        <div class=\"form-group\">
        <label for=\"voteSite\">Select Site:</label>
        <select name=\"votingsite\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"voteSite\" required>
        <option value=\"\" disabled selected>Select Site...</option>";
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>
        </div>";
        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"15\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Username\" required autocomplete=\"off\"/><br/>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"15\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"" . $_SESSION['name'] . "\" value=\"" . $_SESSION['name'] . "\"required autocomplete=\"off\"/><br/>";
        }
?>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Vote &raquo;</button>
</form> 
<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script> $('#myModal').modal('show'); </script>
    <?php
    }
?>
<?php
} else {
?>

<link href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>assets/css/<?php echo $theme; ?>.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>assets/css/addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>assets/css/<?php echo $themetype;?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php
}
?>
```

The modal works just fine, its just the form is not submitting/executing the php code.

Any and all help appreciated!

EDIT: 
I was told, although not W3C valid, that action tags aren't necessary if you wanted the script to start its self. Also just learned from (According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp the form tag is not required in HTML5 :O) So

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
```

is the same as

```
<form method="post">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1) There's no action specified in the "form" tag?

2) Maybe you should change

```
<button type="submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form">
```

3) Try to add this code to see if there's really no post data, because $_POST['submit'] is not specified...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    echo "there's a post submitted";
}
```

4) Try to clean up your PHP code, use proper OO principles / patterns to manage forms and data.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp the form tag is not required in HTML5. No need for the down vote guys! :(